# Field ID into formula field on Field Trip

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am currently trying to create a formula field on the FieldTrip custom object in Salesforce. The field needs to capture the Field ID. I know you can find the ID from the URL, but for reporting purposes, it would be nice to have this field to reference rather than having to navigate to setup and search for the field to get the ID.

I tried using CASESAFEID(Field.ID), but that did not work. I have researched this formula and field and have not found much on it, is it doable?

Comment: Create a text formula and just put "Id" into it.

Comment: You don't need the object name here, just do `CASESAFEID(Id)`.  Also note that the object name is incorrect anyway, you need to use the API name of the object.